# ADDing Django's Q() objects and get two exclusive JOIN ONs

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-q

So this is the scenario:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    ...
class Aktion(models.Model):
    ...

class Aktionsteilnahme(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    aktion = models.ForeignKey(Aktion)
```

The problem now is, that I'm dynamically constructing rather complex queries based on `Q()`-objects. They end up like this:

```
Person.objects.filter(
    Q((Q()|Q(aktionsteilnahme__aktion=302))&
    (Q()|Q(aktionsteilnahme__aktion=547)))
)
```

which can (and automatically will) be reduced to:

```
Person.objects.filter(
    Q(aktionsteilnahme__aktion=302)&
    Q(aktionsteilnahme__aktion=547)
)
```

The **problem** now is, that this results in a SQL like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM person
LEFT OUTER JOIN aktionsteilnahme ON ( person.id = aktionsteilnahme.person_id )
WHERE (aktionsteilnahme.aktion = 2890 AND aktionsteilnahme.aktion = 5924)
```

What I would actually need however is:

```
Person.objects.filter(Q(aktionsteilnahme__aktion=302))
    .filter(Q(aktionsteilnahme__aktion=547))
```

resulting in what I would actually need:

```sql
SELECT * FROM person
INNER JOIN aktionsteilnahme ON ( person.id = aktionsteilnahme.person_id )
INNER JOIN aktionsteilnahme T4 ON ( person.id = T4.person_id )
WHERE (aktionsteilnahme.aktion = 302 AND T4.aktion = 547)
```

I can't use the proposed solution though because all of it is gonna be `OR`'ed again.

I would have to be able to do something like:

```
Person.objects.filter(
    Q(
      Q(aktionsteilnahme__aktion=302))
      .filter(Q(aktionsteilnahme__aktion=547))
    )
    |
    Q(other_q_filters)
)
```

Answer (score 2):

After fiddling some more I realized: Django QuerySets can be `OR`'ed.

My solution therefore is now to create something like this:

```
Person.objects.filter(Q(aktionsteilnahme__aktion=302))
      .filter(Q(aktionsteilnahme__aktion=547))
|
Person.objects.filter(Q(other_q_filters))
```

All the inner `AND`s are now concatenated using filters, and the outer-most `OR`s are boolean `|` directly on the QuerySets.

***Heads up!*** Requests get **much slower** due to inner subqueries always being completely evaluated (no more "limit 20")
and 
`OR`-ing QuerySets will result in multiple entries - so a final

```
(QuerySet | QuerySet | QuerySet).distinct()
```

will usually be necessary.