# Django: Can we use Joins in filter(id__in = RawSQL(),[])

Tags: python, django, django-views

I want to use join in Django QuerySet, not RawQuerySet

```
     records = MailBoxEmailViewLog.objects.filter(evl_id__in=RawSQL(
        '''SELECT a.*, b.*
        FROM AT_MailBoxEmailViewLogs a
        INNER JOIN AT_MailBoxs b ON b.mail_box_id = a.evl_mail_box_id''',
        []
    )).values()
    return HttpResponse(records)
```

I run this but I get this error
('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS. (116) (SQLExecDirectW)')

Comment: basically I want both tables data as QuerySet, not RawQuerySet

Comment: please check out this reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48128714/how-to-make-an-inner-join-in-django