# I have a huge but not complex sql query that must convert to django orm query

Tags: sql, django, orm

I have to convert the following sql query but i don't know how to convert it to equal query in django orm I would be very happy if you can :)))

```
select dialog_messages.*, 
    sender.first_name as sender_first_name,
     sender.last_name as sender_last_name,
     sender.cell_number as sender_cell_number,
     sender.avatar_full_path as sender_avatar_full_path, receiver.first_name as receiver_first_name,
     receiver.first_name as receiver_first_name,
     receiver.last_name as receiver_last_name,
     receiver.cell_number as receiver_cell_number, receiver.avatar_full_path as receiver_avatar_full_path from dialog_messages`` inner join user sender on ``sender``.``user_id`` = dialog_messages``.``sender_id`` inner join user receiver on receiver``.``user_id`` = ``dialog_messages``.``receiver_id`` where `dialog_id`` = ? order by ``dialog_messages``.``id`` desc
```

Comment: You should post your models. Anyway, this answer could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48128714/how-to-make-an-inner-join-in-django

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `select_related` (and also look at `prefetch_related`). You can check the reference at:

- [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#select-related)
- [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related)

In your code, without knowing more about your models I think you could start with something like:

```
DialogMessage.objects.select_related('sender', 'receiver')
```