# How to access an element of a model after a join in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

My post is similar to this one except I can't access an item : [Stackoverflow : How to make an Inner Join in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48128714/how-to-make-an-inner-join-in-django)

I want to display in an Html the locomotive number and the name of the customer who owns this locomotive. But they are in different tables.

Here is my **models.py**

```
class Client(models.Model):
    client_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.client_name


class Locomotive(models.Model):
    locomotive_number_id = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, unique=True)
    locomotive_asset_id = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, unique=True)
    locomotive_client = models.ForeignKey(Client, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.locomotive_number_id
```

Here is my **views.py**

```
def settings(request):

    my_clients = Client.objects.values_list('client_name', flat=True)
    my_locomotives = Locomotive.objects.select_related('locomotive_client')
    return render(request, 'home/settings.html', context={"my_clients": my_clients,"my_locomotives": my_locomotives})
```

if I print my_locomotives.query I get this :

```
print(str(my_locomotives.query))
```

```
SELECT 
 "foo_bar_locomotive"."id",
 "foo_bar_locomotive"."locomotive_number_id",
 "foo_bar_locomotive"."locomotive_asset_id",
 "foo_bar_locomotive"."locomotive_client_id",
 "something1_something2_client"."id",
 "something1_something2_client"."client_name"
FROM "foo_bar_locomotive"
 INNER JOIN "something1_something2_client" ON ("foo_bar_locomotive"."locomotive_client_id" = "something1_something2_client"."id")
```

Here is the html code that allows me to display the list of locomotives. Except that I can't display the name of the customer who owns the locomotive.

```
{% for elements in my_locomotives %}
    <option value="{{elements}}">{{elements}} - {{elements.client_name}}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

How can I do to display this:

Locomotive N° 550XXXYYY - CUSTXXXYYY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly what you wanted to achieve, then you just have to do `elements.locomotive_client.client_name` in your template to get your client name. You'd then have something like that :

```
{% for elements in my_locomotives %}
    <option value="{{elements}}">Locomotive N°{{elements.locomotive_number_id}} - {{elements.locomotive_client.client_name}}</option>
{% endfor %}
```