# I want to Compare two tables Column (Table1 - Balance_sheet, Table2- Account_list) (Column-split,column-account) and get the similar data in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

models.py:

```
 class Balance_Sheet(models.Model): #name of the table

    # date = models.DateField() # Name of the column
    # transaction_type = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=False)
    # num = models.IntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    # description = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    split = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=False)
   

    # class Meta:
    #     abstract : True
    
class Account_List(models.Model):
    account = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True,null=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True, null=True)
    split =models.ForeignKey(Balance_Sheet,null=False, default=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Account : {0} Type : {1} '.format(self.account,self.type)
```

views.py:

```
def DisplayUVL(request):

    # Excel page changes
    Ven_list = Balance_Sheet.objects.filter(account_list__isnull=True).values_list('split', flat=True)
    print("SQL Query:",Ven_list.query)
    context = {
        'items': Ven_list
        # 'header': 'Vendor List'
       
    }
    return render(request, 'services2.html', context)
```

Answer (score 1):

`select_relations` might be helpful to you to compare two table information and get the common one. `select_relations` is the native way.

If you are using postgressql you can use inner join SQL queries directly.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48128714/how-to-make-an-inner-join-in-django#:%7E:text=InnerJoin%20implies%20the%20%22common%22%20section,publication%2C%20giving%20you%20ENTIRE%20dataset.) might helpful for you.

Comment: Can you please give me the query for that